# How to rebuild MobileVLCKit in Mac after change the source code

Tags: ios, swift, build, compilation, vlc

Because I have to change the dialog output of VLC in my swift project, I changed the source code of MobileVLCKit in `MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/src/input.c`.

After above change, I used `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -n` to rebuild the VLC. But the dialog output was not change.

I also used `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh` to rebuild the VLC, but it gave me the following message:
`[info] Preparing build dirs
Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.`

Could anyone tell me how to change the source code and rebuild the VLC correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: It says that you didn't commit the changes you made. Have you ever tried to commit the change and rebuilt it??

Comment: Is there any way to just build the VLC? I don't want to commit this.

Comment: I don't know if there is but It wouldn't be that bad to commit your changes :)

Comment: Please give the MVK version. -n should do just that.

Comment: The MVK version  is 2.2.2.
 Should I delete some files that generated after use `./buildMobileVLCKit.sh` and rebuild it again? Thanks